# PHP SOAP xml namespace missing from WSDL

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I am trying to connect to a SOAP server with PHP in WSDL mode.
In the WSDL file there are defined serveral xmlns in the header.
I am creating a request with the client like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="NS1" xmlns:ns2="NS2" xmlns:ns3="NS3">
 <env:Body>
  <ns3:calculate>
   <ns1:something>01</ns1:something>
    <ns3:calcnode>
     <ns1:beginning>2020-07-01</ns1:beginning>
     <ns3:data>
      <ns1:Hauptfaelligkeit>01.07</ns1:Hauptfaelligkeit>
      <ns3:someothernode>
       <ns3:code>AH</ns3:code>
       <EL-Sum SumCd="ABC" Sum="20000000"/>
       <ns3:something>VB</ns3:something>
       <EL-Test TestCd="A" TestVal="9"/>
      </ns3:someothernode>
     </ns3:data>
    </ns3:calcnode>
  </ns3:calculate>
 </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I've modified it a bit because the WSDL is confidental so I cannot provide it.
The problem is with  there should be a NS4 but it isn't imported so the SOAP server doesn't get the value.

I found a solution that I can modify the XSD of NS4 and add elementFormDefault=qualified but I cannot do this because I cannot load the locally need to leave them remote.
Can I add the NS manually in the header?

Thanks

Comment: You are making this XML document? If so, you should be able to just add that namespace, I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Yes this is what I generated, the problem is that I added EL-Test and EL-Sum to my array and it gets into the XML and Soap call, but the SOAP client doensn't notice that these elements are part of the xmlns:ns4 which isn't loaded in the client. So they have no ns element and the server doesn't read them.